# Monero Wallet Fee Calculation

Tags: wallet

How to calculate the transaction fee when transferring to a wallet in the simplest way?
Is there a calculator?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Monero CLI wallet, there is a command `fee`:

```
[wallet xxxxxx]: help fee
Command usage: 
  fee

Command description: 
  Print the information about the current fee and transaction backlog.
```

You are also shown and asked to confirm the fee before sending a transaction.

Other wallets behave in the same way.